# Использование лямбда функций в параметрах метода c++

Tags: c#, c++, lambda

У меня есть такой метод в c#:

```
    public double[] GetCoordinates(Func<Point3D, double> func)
    {
        var values = new List<double>();
        foreach (var p in _points)
        {
            values.Add(func(p));
        }
        return values.ToArray();
    }
```

Вызвать его я могу следующим образом:

```
GetCoordinates(d => d.X)
GetCoordinates(d => d.Y)
GetCoordinates(d => d.Z)
```

Этот метод позволяет "вытащить" разные массивы, в зависимости от указанной функции при вызове метода.

_points это список структур Point3D, структура Point3D содержит три поля double x, double y, double z.

Метод написан с целью объединения трех методов:

```
    public List<double> GetPointsX()
    {
        List<double> x = new List<double> ();
        foreach (var p in _points)
        {
            x.Add(p.X);
        }
        return x;
    }

    public List<double> GetPointsY()
    {
        List<double> y = new List<double> ();
        foreach (var p in _points)
        {
            y.Add(p.Y);
        }
        return y;
    }

    public List<double> GetPointsZ()
    {
        List<double> z = new List<double> ();
        foreach (var p in _points)
        {
            z.Add(p.Z);
        }
        return z;
    }
```

которые по сути выполняют одни и те же действия - возвращали из списка структур Point3D список отдельных значений для x, y, z

Можно ли этот объединенный метод переписать на с++? Может быть есть аналоги делегата Func в c++?

Comment: @Abyx, т.е. переписать на с++

Comment: Прямо никак, в C++ нету `Func<Point3D, double>`. Какую сигнатуру вы хотите?

Comment: Вы не указали тип d, с++ поддерживает подстановку функций, и подстановку функций класса. Т.е. `pillar.GetCoordinates(d.X)` можно записать, если X - функция. А сама GetCoordinates будет где-то так `public: double* GetCoordinates(double* (func*)(Point3D arg) )` (последнее и есть пример сигнатуры, о которой вам пишут)

Comment: @Abyx: Ну или бестиповой `template`, как обычно делают :)

Comment: О, в вопросе появилось больше конкретики.

Comment: @nick_n_a, d типа Point3D.

Comment: @VladD и больше закрытости

Comment: А d.X какой тип имеет? Если double - то смысл функции... Наверно я запутался, вы "разверните" лямду, тогда хорошо запишется в c++.

Comment: @alexolut: Я пока не вполне понимаю связь между «можно ли переписать» (ответ: да) и сразу вдруг «реализация должна».

Comment: После развертки лямды выводы следующие - это можно сделать через `#define` что будет не оч красиво. Через template протащить свойство - не, не получится (если в с++14 ничего такого что я не знаю не добавили). Разве что число 1,2,3 и лепить сase.

Comment: @nick_n_a, ясно, значит красиво никак не получится написать такой метод(

Comment: Покажу  `#define getCoordinates(list,y) GetCoordinates##y(list)` один из вариантов

Comment: Через #define аналогичным способом можно "свернуть код" трех функций (что б код был для троих одинаковый и в одном месте) используя параметр, подставив X Y Z в аргумент при #define. Тогда код будет компактнее.

Comment: Лямбды для это задачи слишком тяжелы. Можно воспользоваться указателями на члены класса. ` GetCoordinates(double Point3D::* memeber) `

Comment: @nick_n_a >>Покажу << Спрячте, и не показывайте :| злых макросов только и не хватало... std::function<std::vector<double>()> func вот 100% аналог вашего указателя на функцию List<double> func() как и на шарпе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообще-то именно в такой постановке (поля координат - это физические открытые всем ветрам поля) выбор конкретной координаты можно реализовать еще средствами "классического" С++ без использования каких-либо "лямбд" или шаблонов. А именно - через указатель на член класса

```
std::vector<double> GetCoordinates(const double (Point3D::*c))
{    
  std::vector<double> values;

  for (const Point3D &p : _points)
    values.push_back(p.*c);

  return values;
}
```

и вызывать как

```
GetCoordinates(&Point3D::x);
GetCoordinates(&Point3D::y);
GetCoordinates(&Point3D::z);
```

Но если вам для преобразования точки в конкретную координату позарез хочется использовать функциональный объект, то это прекрасно и более гибко (хоть и менее эффективно) решится через `std::function<double (const Point3D &)>`.

Или можно обойтись без громоздкой `std::function` и ограничиться лишь указателем на функцию

```
std::vector<double> GetCoordinates(double (*func)(const Point3D &))
{    
  std::vector<double> values;

  for (const Point3D &p : _points)
    values.push_back(func(p));

  return values;
}

...
GetCoordinates([](const Point3D &p) { return p.x; });
GetCoordinates([](const Point3D &p) { return p.y; });
GetCoordinates([](const Point3D &p) { return p.z; });
```

В данном случае при вызове `GetCoordinates` мы используем тот факт, что lambda без capture является неявно преобразуемой к обычному указателю на функцию.